# Получить несколько документов из CouchDB

Tags: node.js, couchdb

Как получить несколько документов через nano (nodejs)?

Например в базе следующие документы

```
{
  total_rows: 3,
  offset: 0,
  rows: [
    {
      id: "https://github.com/dscape/nano",
      key: 2015
    },
    {
      id: "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/",
      key: 2015
    },
    {
      id: "https://ru.wikipedia.org",
      key: 2015
    },
    {
      id: "https://ru.wikipedia.org/kill",
      key: 2016
    }
  ]
}
```

с помощью функции (примерно):

```
likes.list([
  "https://github.com/dscape/nano",
  "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
],function(err, body) {
  body.rows.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc);
  });
});
```

Получить на выходе

```
{
  total_rows: 2,
  offset: 0,
  rows: [
    {
      id: "https://github.com/dscape/nano",
      key: 2015
    },
    {
      id: "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/",
      key: 2015
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите делать запрос по нескольким ключам одновременно или что?

Comment: да, массив ключей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выборки сразу нескольких документов из коллекции по их ключам в CouchDB существует специальный API метод [`POST /{db}/_all_docs`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#post--db-_all_docs). HTTP запрос в этом случае должен иметь вид:

```
POST /db/_all_docs?include_docs=true HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 51
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:5984

{
   "keys" : [
       "asd",
       "qwe"
   ]
}
```

В nano, для этого используется метод [`db.fetch`](https://github.com/dscape/nano#dbfetchdocnames-params-callback):

```
var db = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984/db');

db.fetch(['asd', 'qwe'], function(err, data) {
    // ...
});
```